# Javascript precision with more than 15 decimals

Tags: javascript, precision, parsefloat

I have a string which I need to convert to number.

The thing is, I have 20 decimals and JS lose precision after 15 or 17 decimals, when trying to use parseFloat.

Example:

```
const number = "0.0000012726726461401083"
const parseNumber = parseFloat(number) // 0.0000012726726461401084
```

Y try to see if libraries like big.js or decimal.js could help me, but I didn't find any solution.

Comment: As a workaround, could you shift the decimal by multiplying the number by 1,000,000 and then divide it again afterwards?

Comment: math.js provides functions with more precision: https://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/numbers.html

Comment: When working with very precise floating point numbers, it's always preferred to attempt to convert the floating point to an integer using some coefficient, and then divide by the same coefficient when you need to display the value. Integer arithmetic is always easier than floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @Dabrowski No, that won't help, precision is 53 bits no matter how large the `number` is.

Comment: @Nicolas That won't help unless you use `BigInteger` though. And it's called fixed-point arithmetic then, which is getting rather ugly unless you wrap it in a helper class/library.

Comment: "*try to see if libraries like big.js or decimal.js could help me*" - please show us **what** you tried. They (and other bigdecimal libraries) should help.

Comment: What I need is to convert a string into a number while maintaining a precision of 20 decimals. I require the data in numerical format rather than a string. Even though these libraries always return a string, I understand that I can still use them for performing calculations. However, in my case, I'm not looking to perform any calculations per se; I simply need to convert the string into a number while preserving the required high precision.

Comment: @diego What you ask is impossible. No `number` can precisely represent the value you desire. Why do you think you need to use a `number`? Why do you think that a `BigNumber` or `Decimal` (from those libraries) is not a "numerical format"?

Comment: @Bergi alright, that's what I was thinking, but I wanted to confirm. Thanks for clarifying it

Comment: "*However, in my case, I'm not looking to perform any calculations per se; I simply need to convert the string into a number while preserving the required high precision.*" why, though? If you're not performing mathematical operations, then a number does not seem to offer any benefit.

Answer (score 0):

What didn't suit you about decimal.js ? It looks exactly like what you would need for that, so have a go at it and try to manually set the precision : https://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/#precision

---

Since the language doesn't natively support higher precision decimals than 17, and decimal.js has a default of 20 precision which you can customize, you will have to work with such a library to perform the necessary operations. The alternative is to handle it with custom code, which unless strictly necessary would not be recommended.

When your calculations are done and you potentially need to use the resulting number elsewhere, you should use a string to do so. If you need to alternate between the string format and the decimal.js library, that is still probably the best js-only option.

If for some reason you really have to resort to native javascript numbers, it is best not to rely on shifting the decimal place as the language still only allows for a fixed precision of 53 bits : Imprecisions will still occur.

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be a comment. Work to provide [good, quality answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) (answers that include nothing more than a question back to the OP and a link are not considered good answers) so that you can get enough reputation to provide comments.

Comment: This libraries, return strings and I need a number.

Comment: @ScottMarcus i need 50 karma to comment. That's what I tried first. I included a solution and a link to the relevant resource which seemed enough to me for an answer

Comment: I understand. As I indicated, work on providing good, quality answers (see link I supplied to learn what that is) to get your reputation high enough to comment. This current answer is really just a question back to the OP and a link, which doesn't constitute an answer here - - that's a comment.

Comment: @diego You can work with this library to perform the necessary operations on your number, and finally use the string format to communicate with the rest of your code or APIs. Since this high of a precision is not supported by the language, you have to resort either to that or do it your own way with custom code, which is the same but more complicated.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I have edited my answer in an attempt to increase its quality and helpfulness.

Comment: "*try to increase the number by multiple base tens to artificially increase the precision you work with*" - that does not increase precision as long as you work with floating-point `number`s. Apart from the last paragraph, your answer is spot-on.

Comment: @Bergi I made an assumption about the proposed implementation and that could indeed leave the door open to some error ; I have made an edit that makes it hopefully more correct.

Comment: No, that is not correct. All `number`s have fixed "double" precision" of 53 bits. It does not matter how large they are, which is just what **floating-point** is all about. You can artificially increase the number of digits before the decimal point, you cannot increase the precision.

Comment: So I have just used the word precision badly ; I meant that, given no integer part on the base number, it could artificially increase precision by allowing to compute precisely on more decimal parts by shifting the decimal. However that leads to more problems in the end. I'll simply remove that part. -- Thanks for your explanations